# When using unpacking(**) in Python can the dictionary your sending to the function include more variables than the function requires?

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning how to unpack dictionaries with function in python and can't seem to get my code to work when my dictionary has a key/index that is not asked for the in the function. Is this something that just isn't possible? I am just trying to understand how unpacking works! Any help is much appreciated.

Check out my code below:

```
def customer_profiles(country, name):
    print("{},{}".format(name, country))

customer_profiles(**{"gender" : "male", "name" : "David" , "country" : "USA"})
```

This is the error message I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                 
  File "luggage.py", line 12, in <module>                                                          
customer_profiles(**{"gender" : "male", "name" : "David" , "country" : "USA"})                 
TypeError: customer_profiles() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gender'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by providing a dummy variable for the rest of the keyword arguments to be put in:

```
def customer_profiles(country, name, **kwargs):
    print("{},{}".format(name, country))

customer_profiles(**{"gender" : "male", "name" : "David" , "country" : "USA"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept an arbitrary amount of keyword args, then only use the ones you need:

```
def customer_profiles(**kwargs):
    print("{},{}".format(kwargs["name"], kwargs["country"]))

customer_profiles(**{"gender" : "male", "name" : "David" , "country" : "USA"})
```

Output:

```
David,USA
```